# Problems to create new component for android platform

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I want to create a new component to be able to use it under the Android platform. I'm following [this guide](https://learncplusplus.org/how-to-make-a-new-windows-fmx-component-in-c/).

For the platform of the new component, I select "FireMonkey for C++", and for the "Ancestor component", I select `TRectangle` (that supports all platforms).

I have no problem creating the new component, but the resulting component only supports the Windows 32-bit platform.

Is it possible to create a new component that supports the Android platform?

Answer (score 0):

As the linked guide explains, the IDE is a Windows 32bit application, so only Windows 32bit packages can be installed into it.

If you want to support other platforms, you need to separate your runtime code (ie, the component itself) from your design-time code (ie, the component registration, editors, etc). Create separate package projects for them, marking the component package as runtime only, and marking the  registration package as design-time only. And make the design-time package require the runtime package.

You can then add more platforms to the project of the runtime package. And you should mark your component itself with the [`ComponentPlatforms`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.ComponentPlatformsAttribute) attribute to specify which platforms it supports.

See Embarcadero's documentation for more details:

[Working with Packages and Components](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_Packages_and_Components_Index)

Comment: I went through the documentation you suggested, "Working with packages and components", and still don't understand what you mean by: "you need to separate your runtime code (i.e. the component itself) from your design-time code of code (ie component registration, editors etc...) .." I have the .cpp and .h files for the new component but I don't know how to include it as a visual component in my project. May be more specific by an ignoramus. Thank you.